# How do I know what all this stuff does?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

This game has all kinds of items, but everytime I find one there doesn't seem to be a description. How do I know what all this stuff does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a general rule, I don't play Binding of Isaac without having the [Wikia Items page](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Items) open.

There's no real in-game method of knowing what each thing does without trying it for yourself. You will, at times, get a brief, one line description in-game when you pick up an item, but they never really give you enough information.

The Wikia, on the other hand, has a detailed list for every item, power-up, pill, trinket, tarot card, etc., in the game. Easily one of the handiest things to have open when you play.

Comment: Not to mention that some items work well together and some other items clash (like laser weapons and bomb weapons).

Comment: This particularly helps me with the Tarot cards, as well as determining what interactions there may be with certain items.